# Me marca un error en el @ de una expresion Regular

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor

Con `javascript` estoy validando que el `email`sea correcto, (si lo pruebo en un html común sin MVC no me tira ningún error). No se si es por `Razor`, pero me marca un error en el primer `else if` justo en el símbolo `@` de la expresion regular, como se solucionaría?

```js
function checkData() {
        //obteniendo el valor de los input de las contraseñas
        clave1 = document.f1.txtClave1.value
        clave2 = document.f1.txtClave2.value
        
        if (clave1 != clave2)
            alert("Las dos contraseñas son distintas!.\nLas contraseñas deben ser iguales!")
         //verifico que el email sea correcto
         //ACA ME MARCA UN ERROR EN EL "@"
        else if(!/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(f1.txtEmail.value))
                alert("Su email no es correcto!")
        else if (validarCamposInput()) // Solo se enviará si los campos están bien
            document.f1.submit()//pulsa el submit y manda los datos del form

        //Other Sentences
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque @ es un caracter especial de razor. Tienes que usarlo doble @@.

Comment: Gracias @crrlos! ahora funciona!